# ModuleNotFoundError when importing sklearn in conda env

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mini-forge

I'm trying to import sklearn in a conda environment, and I'm getting this error:

[image]

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random.bit_generator'
```

I am using an M1 Mac Pro. See the error code below. [see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIuUZ.png)

````
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan, parse_version
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 20, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 441, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 43, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import _discrete_distns
  File "/Users/nikhil/miniforge3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .biasedurn import (_PyFishersNCHypergeometric,
  File "biasedurn.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.stats.biasedurn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random.bit_generator'```
````

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the versions of `scikit-learn`, `numpy`, and `scipy` you are using? You may have to upgrade or re-install them. You can show the version by doing: `import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)`

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the numpy package installed in your environment.
To resolve this error, You need to execute the below code lines:

```
conda install numpy --force-reinstall
```

Or

```
!pip install numpy
!pip install sklearn
```